# Firebase Deploy Error

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am trying to add the push notification feature in my android project using nodejs using firebase.I have installed the firebase tools and connected with my project.

Here is the index.js file

```
'use strict'

    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require ('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event =>
    {
      const receiver_id = event.params.receiver_id;
      const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;
      console.log('We have new notification to send to : ', receiver_id);

      if(!event.data.val())
      {
        return console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database :', notification_id);
      }

    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${receiver_id}/device_token`).once('value');

    return deviceToken.then(response =>
    {
        const token_id = result.val();
        const payload =
        {
            notification:
            {
                title: "Friend Request",
                body: "You have received a new Friend Request",
                icon: "default"
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>
        {
            console.log('This was the notification feature');
        });


    });

});
```

When I'm trying to deploy the file, I'm getting this error :

33:11  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
33:66  error
 Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

✖ 2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error says `Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return` so, each time you call `then()`, you must add an return statement like this

```
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>
    {
        console.log('This was the notification feature');
  //add return statement here
      return null;
    });
```

Comment: This solved my error but was still showing 1 warning.

Comment: Please can upvote my answer? And what says this warning